# How to handle iPhone 4s, 5 and 6 screen size, and make all the contents look the same across al the devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I am using Xcode 6.1 and in one of the views I have, contains many labels. However, these labels look different in each different devices. Although I have add constraints to all the labels, but still facing the same issue.

How can I get the same view layout across all devices? 
How can I make the width and height for each label is flexible, depends on the screen size?
Do I need to design different xib for each device?

The following images showing the result am getting, with auto resize enabled, and constants been added.

on iPhone 6 
[image]

on iPhone 5

[image]

on iPhone iOS 7.1
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have provided with a simple solution . Using **Aspect ratio constraint** we can get a relative look in all device screens.

I had the same issue and I found this >>
http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

So when designing for lowest to highest screen resolution we can't set a specific width and height for all controls as it may look weird. So using this constraint we can have a relative look for all screens.

If you don't want to use constraints or you want to keep the same width & height , you can add scrollview to hold all controls. For that you can set a resizing frame for scrollview with fixed content size .

Comment: This is the must correct answer. I had to learn how to do constraints properly. Also, when having such a nasty form, having all the fields in a scroll view is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this...

1) Go to xib file and uncheck the Auto layout

[image]

2) Then set the autosizing manually in the following manner for each and every subview.

[image]

Comment: Fixed my problem :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.view.bounds.size.width` to get the width of screen, then use relative value to initialize all labels.

Comment: well, this is what I have done, but I have many other storyboard like this, it is take time to write code for all of them, and I have to disable the auto layout in this case. anyway thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

One soultion is that you can Design a story board for each screen size like one for iphone 5, one for iphone 6 and one for iphone 6+ and in your AppDelegate method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" you can get the screen size and popup corresponding storyboard 
in this wasy you can set different constraints according to different screen size