# App looks fine on iPhone 6, but total mess on other devices, even with constraints

Tags: swift

As the title says, my app looks great on iPhone 6, which is the device that I code against (actual device, not simulator), however when I open the app on a different device, like iPad Air2 simulator, or iPhone 7s simulator, the app is a total mess. All of the subviews are meshed together.

In my code, I programmatically place subviews with the following constraint format:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[v0]-230-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userIdLabel]))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-130-[v0]-510-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userIdLabel]))
```

From my understanding of constraints, if you use constraints to place your subviews, then they will stay in the same position across devices. However, I'm starting to feel like I have misunderstood the concept of constraints.

Could you guys help point me in the right direction, in regards to constraints?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to guess from what you've said, but try using Xcode's view debugging feature while the app is running.  It can show you the constraints that are in effect to help diagnose why things are where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have misunderstood the concept of constraints. Providing constant values to the constraints will not make the app look same across different devices. For that, you should simply consider the w/h of the current device and then proportionally adjust the view of your app in certain ratio.

Also please have a look at these:
[Autolayout views always same size on different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878202/autolayout-views-always-same-size-on-different-screen-sizes)

[How to use autolayout to scale view for all screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458858/how-to-use-autolayout-to-scale-view-for-all-screen-sizes?rq=1)

[How to handle iPhone 4s, 5 and 6 screen size, and make all the contents look the same across al the devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665028/how-to-handle-iphone-4s-5-and-6-screen-size-and-make-all-the-contents-look-the?rq=1)

**Tutorial:**
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2